# How to redirect URL with a "?" in the middle that is not a query

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I redirect *a URL that has a "?" in the middle of it* (not like a typical query string)?

**The problem URL:**

```
https://example.com/michigan/jobs/?/jobs/
```

**I need to rewrite or redirect it to:**

```
https://example.com/michigan/jobs/
```

I have tried all of these, and none of them work (no change):

```
 1. Redirect 301 https://example.com/michigan/jobs/?/jobs/ https://example.com/michigan/jobs/
 2. Redirect 301 /michigan/jobs/?/jobs/ /michigan/jobs/
 3. RedirectMatch 302 ^/michigan/jobs/?/jobs/ /michigan/jobs/
 4. RewriteRule ^/michigan/jobs/?/jobs/$ /michigan/jobs/ [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^michigan/jobs/?/jobs /michigan/jobs/
```

I've tried a bunch of different "generators" but they don't seem to detect the random "?" in the middle of things.

What would be the correct redirect or rewrite rule to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

> not like a typical query string

Although that IS a query string, just like any other. Anything after the first `?` is a query string, whether that is the intention or not is another matter. So, in your example `/jobs/` is the *query string*.

The `Redirect`, `RedirectMatch` and `RewriteRule` directives all match against the URL-path only, which notably excludes the query string.

To match the query string, you need to use mod_rewrite and an additional `RewriteCond` directive (a "condition") that compares against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable, together with a `RewriteRule`.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Removes the query string from "/michigan/jobs/?/jobs/"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/jobs/$
RewriteRule ^michigan/jobs/$ /$0 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The `$0` backreference contains the full match from the `RewriteRule` *pattern* - basically the full URL-path. This just saves repetition.

The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag then discards the original query string from the redirect response, otherwise it is passed through by default.

Note that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.